# Updating state based on fetches

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetches movies OMDB API data you can see 2 fetches, each fetch give array of 10 objects data only,
but the data is being incremented on every search, even though I kept i.e reseting state `setmovieData([])` at the beginning of the function.

```js
useEffect(
  function () {
    async function requestMovieData() {
      setmovieData([]);
      const res1 = await fetch(
        `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=51b8382f&s=${query}`,
      );
      const res2 = await fetch(
        `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=51b8382f&s=${query}&page=1`,
      );

      const data1 = await res1.json();
      const data2 = await res2.json();

      if ((data1.Response = "True" && data1.Search)) {
        setmovieData([...movieData, ...data1.Search]);
      }
      if ((data2.Response = "True" && data2.Search)) {
        setmovieData([...movieData, ...data2.Search]);
      }
    }

    requestMovieData();
  },
  [query],
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here...

1. State changes are asynchronous so `setmovieData([])` may not be applied by the time you add more data
2. Along the same lines, setting state based on previous state like with `setmovieData([...movieData, ...data1.Search])` can have unforeseen effects as the current state may not be what you think

Generally, you can use an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) to avoid point #2 but I would advise fetching and collecting all the data at once and then setting state without worrying about what it is or was

```js
// Stand-alone function that can be defined outside your component
const fetchMovies = async (query, page) => {

  // URLSearchParams ensures correct encoding
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    apikey: "51b8382f",
    s: query,
  });
  if (page) {
    params.append("page", page);
  }

  const res = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?${params}`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Fetch failed: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  const { Response, Search } = await res.json();
  return Response === "True" ? Search : [];
};
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all([fetchMovies(query), fetchMovies(query, 1)])
    .then((movies) => setmovieData(movies.flat()))
    .catch(console.error);
}, [query]);
```

Comment: Absolutely Loved ❤ your answer, But what do you mean by " State changes are asynchronous so setmovieData([]) may not be applied by the time you add more data "

Comment: Can you even explain, what mistake I did in my code ?

Comment: @KondavetiCharan calling `setmovieData()` won't change the current value of `movieData` until the next render, no matter what you pass to it. See the React docs link in my answer as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/283366) for more information